# Append Lists or Array from .csv into template .csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, xlsxwriter

This seems relatively straightforward, but as a relatively new user to Python I could use some direction.

I am looking to import a .csv file and either make lists or arrays using numpy of the columns in that .csv file. I then want to take those lists or arrays and append them to the columns of a template .csv file. Once appended I would like to save it as an .xlsx. I imagine that I will need to use both pandas and numpy (if using arrays).

Example Imported .csv (headers in row 1)

```
Date,Test#,Type
04/12/18,432,D
04/13/18,300,N
04/15/18,433,D
```

Template (headers are in row 4) (Some Formatted Labeling text in row 1 and 2)(Cells in column 2 are formatted to populate column 4 and cells in column 3 are formatted to populate column 5.)

```
Results of Tests
G Inc.

Date,Test Number,Type,Content,Curve
```

Append and save to xlsx

I am not necessarily looking for someone to write this out, more so direct me so that I can learn to write this on my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')` from the pandas module to easily read csv file in python. For the excel export, take a look the the [`to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) function:

```
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')    
writer.save()
```

To modify the datas, look at the [pandas documentation for DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).